# What does the '*' and ')' mean in the output of qDebug()<<QByteArray?

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray, qdebug

Code:

```
QByteArray receive=serialport.readAll();
qDebug()<<"receive="<<receive;
```

qDebug output:

```
receive= "\x02\x03*\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x9D)"
```

What does the `*` and `)` mean?

Answer (score 0):

`'*'` is `\x2a` and `')'` is `\x29`.

I guess the `qDebug()<<QByteArray` prints a byte as a ASCII symbol if it's printable, and prints its value if not.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html):

> Writes the byte array, t, to the stream and returns a reference to the stream. Normally, `QDebug` prints the array inside quotes and transforms control or non-US-ASCII characters to their C escape sequences (`\xAB`). This way, the output is always 7-bit clean and the string can be copied from the output and pasted back into C++ sources, if necessary.
>
> To print non-printable characters without transformation, enable the `noquote()` functionality. Note that some `QDebug` backends might not be 8-bit clean.
>
> [QDebug Class - `QDebug &QDebug::operator<<(const QByteArray &t)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html#operator-lt-lt-20)

So printable ASCII characters will be printed as characters, other byte values will be escaped